# Drawing line of sight between two actors

Tags: android, libgdx

I am fresh learner of LibGDX. I am trying to learn LibGDX by developing a demo game. In the game when an army and enemy are visible to each other I want to draw a line of sight between them to prove that they see each other. The line of sight should increase gradually, say something like when we transfer file in windows 7 the green portion increases gradually. I am working with scene2D and have implemented Screen interface of scene2D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed the game using AndEngine and i have used AndEngine box2D physics and i update the position between two players continuously as follows:
I have two players one player and other enemy. I have drawn the line and the end position of the line is given by player and enemy positions. I have done by getting their coordinates

```
//line of sight
final Line e1line = new Line(player.getX(), player.getY(), enemy.getX(), enemy.getY())
```

And finally i have used update handler to continusely move the line as the player moves as follows:

```
IUpdateHandler updatehand = new IUpdateHandler(){
@Override
public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

// line of sight and notifier update
e1line.setPosition(player.getX(), player.getY(), enemy1.getX(), enemy1.getY());
}
@Override
public void reset() {}
};
```

Comment: AndEngine and LibGDX are quite different but the logic is same. Your answer is also helpful, since I am using LibGDX so Menno Gouw and Peter R answers will help me exactly what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into a physics library. Either use it explicitly in your app (like Box2d or libgdx's BulletPhysics). Both of these have a concept of raycasting and some form of ray cast callback. This allows you to pick a "starting point" for your "line of sight" and see what the raycast hits/collides with.

If you don't want to use the physics library in your app, you could at least look at the source code for both, and roll your own, slimmed down functionality to achieve your line of sight goals.

Answer (score 1):

So you are looking for something visually for the player and for calculations? I have no clue what you mean by the windows 7 file transfer thing.

It all depends on how accurate you want to have things but you need some kind of ray casting like Peter R is saying. You have libraries for this but depending on what you want this can be easy to implement yourself.

You take the `Vector` of a unit or army and the `Vector` of the enemy. Then check for obstructions between those `Vectors`. You should have a `float`for the distance each step of the line, the higher this is the more efficient but also less accurate since it could step over a small object.

Some crude untested pseudo code for 2D:

```
RayCast(Vector v1, Vector v2)
{
    Vector2 p = v1;
    Vector2 direction = (v2 - v1).normalize;
    float distance = 0.5f;
    float totalDistance = 200;

    while (Distance(p & v2) > distance && Distance(p & v1) < totalDistance)
    {
         p += direction * distance;
         if (some obstruction is at p)
         {
             //no line of sight
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: This really helped me to draw line of sight. I mean that the line of sight should gradually reach from army to enemy or vice versa(windows 7 file trasnfer). I think i could use some delay here. Thank you for the help